# Reactive Global Transaction with multiple databases (MySQL, MongoDB)

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-transactions, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I'm using MYSQL with `R2DBC` (with `spring-data-r2dbc` and `jasync-r2dbc-mysql`) and Reactive Mongo with `spring-data-mongo-reactive`.
I want to set transaction which includes both operations.
At first, I considered `JTA` and `ChainedTransactionManager` but as I know, both of them implements `PlatformTransactionManager`, not `ReactiveTransactionManager`.

Considering that both `R2DBCTransactionManager` of `spring-data-r2dbc` and `ReactiveMongoTransactionManager` of `spring-data-mongodb` implements `AbstractReactiveTransactionManager`, is there any way to integrate them in one transaction?

Comment: I don't see why not, have you tried it? To do this with something that uses `PlatformTransactionManager`, just mark the parent method that calls both data sources with `@Transactional`

Comment: @stringy05 Yes, I tried but it doesn't work. And both of them does not implement `PlatformTransactionManager` but `AbstractReactiveTransactionManager.` Or do you think that reactive transaction should work similar with normal transaction as for `@Transactional`?

Comment: what am I talking about here? This question is basically - can spring reactive do XA (that is distributed) transactions? Not without a reactive distributed transaction manager and I dont think that exists yet, although there's some O'Reilly page that says it can be done with the SAGA pattern.. here's the link https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-reactive-programming/9781787284951/bcb4b700-44fc-4376-a9c2-df2af3e9a2a8.xhtml but I haven't read it and cant vouch if it works or not

Comment: @stringy05 I newly checked that even normal Mongo does not support for XA. As you said, maybe reactive XA support does not even exist that I cannot find any reference for it.. Thank you for introducing SAGA pattern, I'll take a look about it.

Comment: yeah, maybe in the future someone will write a reactive version of atomikos